# Inflate two Layouts at the same time

Tags: android, listview, layout

Iḿ trying to inflate two Layouts at the same time in a ListView. I actually made it but it is not exactly what I wanted.

This is the getView code in my adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
View v = convertView;
//Create InstalacionEnLista object
Instalacion inst = items.get(position);
int id = inst.getIdCategoria();
if(id == 1){
     if (convertView == null || convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_categoria_header_titulo)==null)
        {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_header_categoria, null);
        TextView nombreCategoria = (TextView)                                               v.findViewById(R.id.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_categoria_header_titulo);
        nombreCategoria.setText("Esto es una categoria");
        }

}else{
    LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_conflecha, null);
    TextView nombre = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_conflecha_tvnombreinstalacion);
    nombre.setText(inst.getNombre());
}
return v;
```

}

If the id is 1, I want both Layouts to inflate, with item information. 
If the id is not =1, I want only one Layout to inflate.

Regards

Comment: Why multiple layouts? Why not have the two `TextViews` in one layout and change the visibility depending on the id?

Comment: I agree, I was working on a similar issue recently and found that using one layout and changing properties of the layout in my adapter to be a simpler option.

Comment: I am implementing sections in the listView. So if an item is in category 1. Then head should show the name of the category followed by the item.

In my code the first element is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem like this:

```
        //Category layout inflate            
    if (convertView == null || convertView.findViewById(R.id.category)==null)
            {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_header_categoria, null);
            //disable click over category
            v.setOnClickListener(null);
            v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            v.setLongClickable(false);

            }
        TextView nombreCategoria = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_categoria_header_titulo);
        nombreCategoria.setText(nombre);




    //simple item layout inflate
    else{

            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_conflecha, null);
            TextView tvNombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_todaslasinstalaciones_conflecha_tvnombreinstalacion);
            tvNombre.setText(nombre);


    }
return v;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your adapter is okay. Are you adding all the rows in your list? 
I mean, what you should do to have it up and running:

0- create the xml files (listView and rows)

1- create the row class (in your case: Instalacion)

2- create the adapter (with getView and so on)

3- create the list of 'Instalacion' objects somewhere (the one that needs the adpater)

4- add elements into this list (InstalacionList)

5- initialize the list (set de adapter and so on)

Hope it helps. If it's needed I can try to post some code.

Comment: Yes. I did all the steps. But in my code the result is:

>section name,
>item2,
item3,
item4,
.....

And i want this:

section name,
item1,
item2,
item3,
item4,
....

Comment: Are the section name and item1 added separately?

Comment: No. It is the same item (Object). For example, Object has properties. item.name, item.address, item.category, ...